# JMS Outbound Gateway response read throttling

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a JMS Outbound Gateway which sends messages out via a request queue and receives messages in via a response queue. I would like to know what is the simplest way to apply throttling to the receive part of messages off the response queue. I have tried setting a `Poller` to the Outbound Gateway but, when I set it, the response messages are not consumed at all. Can a `Poller` be used in Outbound Gateways for the purpose of message consumption throttling? If so, how? If not, how can I best throttle message response consumption instead?

My stack is:

```
o.s.i:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.RC1
o.s.i:spring-integration-jms:4.0.4.RELEASE
```

My IntegrationgConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("test.request.ch")
            .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                    .receiveTimeout(45000)
                    .requestDestination("REQUEST_QUEUE")
                    .replyDestination("RESPONSE_QUEUE")
                    .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"), e -> {
                    e.requiresReply(true);
                    e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(2)); // when this poller is set, response messages are not consumed at all...
                })
            .handle("testService",
                    "testMethod")
            .channel("test.response.ch").get();
    }

    ...
}
```

Cheers,
PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to fetch messages from the `response queue` the `.poller()` doesn't help you.

We need `poller` if our endpoint's `input-channel` (in your case `test.request.ch`) is a `PollableChannel`. See docs on the matter.

There `.replyContainer()` option on the `Jms.outboundGateway` for you. With that you can configure `concurrentConsumers` options to achieve better throughput on `response queue`.

Otherwise the `JmsOutboundGateway` creates `MessageConsumer` for each request message.

Comment: Having reviewed the SI flow as a whole, and pretty much along the lines of what you are saying... it turns out we don't actually need to throttle on the JMS Outbound Gateway at all. Instead, we are now throttling on the initial JMS Inbound Adapter at the start of the whole flow by means of setting a Poller as well as a ThreadPoolExecutor (not shown in the code snippet above!). I suppose this is synonymous to what you meant with regards to setting the Poller on the input-channel. Thanks for the handy tip!

Comment: Correct. Because `inbound-channel-adapter` is `pollable` too. See `AbstractPollingEndpoint` and its implementations. They require `poller`.